# How to bundle a JS script with Vite + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundle, vite

I have a React app with Vite on which I'm implementing an external JS script.

I load the script on `index.html` and it works perfectly on development, but when I bundle it for production the script is not loaded.
At first, I received an error that I needed to include `type="module"` when loading the script and that fixed the error, but when I go to the part of the application that uses that script, I get the error that is not defined.

The script is in `/vendors/faceio/fio.js`.

```html
<body>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.faceio.net/fio.js"></script> -->
    <script type="module" src="/vendors/faceio/fio.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/index.jsx"></script>
    <script>
        const global = globalThis;
    </script>
    <!--
        This HTML file is a template.
        If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

        You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
        The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

        To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
        To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>
```

Can anyone point out how to make this work please.

Answer (score 1):

You can just import it in your main.jsx file.

```js
import "./vendors/faceio/fio.js"

const faceio = new faceIO("fioa414d");
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your index.html file, the code inside `<body></body>` tag should look like this.

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.faceio.net/fio.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
 <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
```

Now inside your `main.jsx` file, or wherever you want to initialize faceIO, use a react hook called `useEffect()`.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App(){
   let faceio;

  useEffect(() => {
    faceio = new faceIO("fioa414d");
  }, []);
}
```

To build your vite application, run `npm run build`. You can preview the build before deploying using `npm run preview` command.

Hope this solves all your issues. Thanks.

To know more about about faceIO, please visit the [official documentation](https://faceio.net/integration-guide) page.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I already tryed that option and it works perfectly on development, but when I build it, vite throws an error that Scripts have to be modules to be bundled